# Change Action Center settings via command line

Tags: command-line, automation, notification-area

I wish to disable action center notifications (turning its messages off).
I need to do this via a batch script that runs on all our test platforms.
I have not been able to find a way to do this.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

You can hide the Action Center icon with the following command:

```
reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer /v HideSCAHealth /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1
```

It won't disable messages (to do that you'd have to edit a binary registry value), but they won't be displayed anymore.

Comment: Just as a note, it looks like the user must logoff/login before the notifications go away.